# Translation of a character to another SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to translate a character from A - B but also in the same query I want to translate B - C if is found on a list. Let's say we have word "Apple" that gets translated to "Orange" but "Orange" it is also on the list and it gets translated to "Coconut", so the final result would be "Coconut". Is this possible ?. I do not want to use a cursor but i just can't find the answer..

```
update tableA
set Value = b.TargetValue
from tableA a
join
tableB b on b.SourceValue = a.Value
```

from my TableA i have let's say a list of fruits for this example i just have the fruit "Apple" on tableA but in tableB i have a translation for that word to "Orange", but also in the same tableB i have a translation for "Orange" to "Coconut" so i would expect to have as final result "Coconut". Does that help? it's my first time sorry if i didn't explain well.

EDIT

I have created a function for this. Hope it helps someone else with the same problem.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[FunctionName]
(
@sourceValue varchar(11)
)
RETURNS varchar(11)
AS
BEGIN

declare @targetId varchar(11) = (select TargetID from tableWithValues where 
SourceID = @sourceValue)

if @targetId is not null and @targetId <> @sourceValue
begin
    set @targetId = dbo.FunctionName(@targetId)
end
else
begin
    return @sourceValue
end

return @targetId
end
```

Comment: Your question doesnt make much sense. Can you show your table, sample data and an expected result? Would be great if you'd also show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Sounds like a left join to a derived table or cte that has another left join?

Comment: What are you expecting for an answer here? We have nothing in the way of details here. Sounds like it might a good case for a recursive cte? But with no information you are not likely going to get any solid response.

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: I recommend either a statement within a statement or a temp table that acts as a go-between.  In other words, run the 2 translations in separate stages.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you get a final dataset by joining both fruit tables, so when you get your final fruit just join that dataset(cte or temp table) with the table you want to update.
Hope this approach helps you solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is general solution for this, but there is a work-around if there are reasonable limits to the number of substitutions.

For example, the A => B => C you describe has two levels of substitution. If the max number of levels is e.g. 5 you can code like this:

```
update tableA
set Value = case when b5.TargetValue is not null then b5.targetValue
            else when b4.TargetValue is not null then b4.TargetValue
            else when b3.TargetValue is not null then b3.TargetValue
            else when b2.TargetValue is not null then b2.TargetValue
            else when b1.TargetValue is not null then b1.TargetValue
            else b0.TargetValue end case
from tableA a
join
tableB b0 on b0.SourceValue = a.Value
left outer join tableB b1 -- outer join for no sub
on b1.SourceValue = b0.TargetValue
left outer join tableB b1
on b2.SourceValue = b1.TargetValue
left outer join tableB b1
on b3.SourceValue = b2.TargetValue
left outer join tableB b1
on b4.SourceValue = b3.TargetValue
left outer join tableB b1
on b5.SourceValue = b4.TargetValue
```

Here, 5 levels are supported: A =>B =>C =>D =>E =>F.  If you have a situation where 6 levels are needed (e.g F => G) then it won't happen, and the result will be F.

Note that the order of the `when bx.TargetValue is not null` statements is important.

Comment: This could work, but i'm working on a function so i can have a clean query. I will post the solution when i solve a little  problem that i have.

Comment: [`COALESCE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql) would make that `set Value=COALESCE(b5.TargetValue,b4.TargetValue,b3.TargetValue,b2.TargetValue,b1.TargetValue,b0.TargetValue)`, a lot tighter to write that.